# grails unidirectional one-to-many

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

this has been bugging me,

lets say i have two model, category and product

```
class Category {
  static hasMany = [products : Product]
  String name
}
..
class Product {
  String name
}
```

now, i want to delete product, which happens to exist in many category. i came up with these lines in my product beforeDelete methods

```
def beforeDelete = {
  Category.list()?.each{
       it.removeFromProducts(this)
    }
}
```

now this may works, but the way i see it, thats a lots of query for one simple task. i know i can get the same result just with a single line of sql string ("delete from category_product where product_id = ?"). but im just curious, is there more sophisticated way to achieve this in grails? (besides executing the sql string)

Answer (score 1):

You could add the following lines to the Category class

```
static mapping = {
    products cascade: "all-delete-orphan"
}
```

and call delete on Category instead. Why are you using a unidirectional relation in this case? Wouldn't it be better with a bi-directional one? In the case above you iterate over all Categories each time you delete a Product which is a resource heavy operation (depending on you many categories you have of course), the better solution would be to find the Category via a bi-directional relation like this:

```
class Product {
    String name
    static belongsTo = [category: Category]
}
```

That was you can easily get to Category from Product and delete it.

See [this blog post](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/07/02/gorm-gotchas-part-2/) on more hints and tips.